# How to create a shiny reactive function with input in a separate R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am new to R and I face a problem when I trying to create a shiny application.

My app contains UI dan Server in a single app.R
I want to create a package that launches a shiny app.

In the server function, I have one reactive element that subset the dataset based on `dateRangeInput` function from the UI.
Here's part of the code in the `UI`

```
df <- coronavirus # I use coronavirus package from CRAN

ui <- sidebarLayout(
          sidebarPanel(
            dateRangeInput(
              inputId = "range",
              label = "Select date range",
              start = "2020-03-01",
              min = "2020-03-01",
              end = "2020-09-27",
              max = "2020-09-27",
              format = "dd/mm/yyyy",
              separator = " - "
            )
```

Originally the reactive code and output plot in `Server` function is

```
server <- function(input,output,session){
 newdate <- reactive({
     df %>% filter(between(date, input$range[1], input$range[2]))
   })

output$plotly <- renderPlotly({
    plot <- newdate() %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = date,
                 y = cases,
                 color = country)) +
      geom_line() 
ggplotly(plot)
}
```

I passed this reactive function into another R file named `newdate.R`

```
#' @export
newdate <- reactive({
  req(input$range)
  df %>% filter(between(date, input$range[1], input$range[2]))
})
```

Then I pass this `newdate()` function into the output plot

```
output$plotly <- renderPlotly({
    plot <- newdate() %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = date,
                 y = cases,
                 color = country)) +
      geom_line() 
ggplotly(plot)
```

There is an error that says

```
Error: object 'input' not found
```

The reactive function work fine when I put them directly in server. However when I try to put in separate R files, it gives me an error.
My question is, how to put the Reactive function that has input argument into another R file?
Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass `input` as argument to the reactive function:

```
newdate <- function(input) {
  reactive({
    req(input$range)
    df %>% filter(between(date, input$range[1], input$range[2]))
  })
}
```

The call to the function in the server is then:

```
plot <- newdate(input)() %>% ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, when I followed yours I got the ``` Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('reactiveExpr', 'reactive', 'function')"```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot `()` because the result is a function. See my edit : `newdate(input)()`